# How to make a main menu and how it works in a game made in libgdx?

Tags: java, menu, libgdx

I want to build a small game for Android devices, and the first thing I want to make is the main menu. I know how to manage them menu state / play state / etc., but I don't have an idea on how to place a background-image, some buttons, if I should use a camera or not, or a viewport, etc.

I basically want a background image, a small black box on the right side which is in which I will add some buttons ("Play", "Exit", etc.).

I already added a background image and a black box as sprites but I'm afraid this is not the good way and I have no idea how to place some text, also if I do it manually it will look different on all devices, etc.

It looks different on PC and my phone and I have no idea on how to build a menu(maybe with tables, scenes, etc.? but I don't know how that works) and I found no useful informations on the internet.

Comment: Have you tried to use Scene2d from libGdx? Scene2d is exactly for what you want. Here is a link to the Scene2d wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d. Additional here is a tutorial where the Main menu will be created: https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-project-setup/

Comment: The problem is I don't understand much from that wiki, it doesn't explain everything. I'm a beginner in libgdx.

Comment: Look at the tutorial or search for other tutorials. StackOverflow is not the perfect place to ask how you can do something if you don't know how it works for those tutorials exists.